# How to list provisioning profiles and installed iOS signing identities?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Environment:

```
Visual Studio 2015 on PC
Visual Studio (Xamarin) on Mac
iPad is connected to Mac
```

My setup used to work fine. From PC, I would be able to debug iOS apps running on the iPad.

Yesterday, I updated the Mac OS as well as my iPad iOS. I may have updated a few other things too. However, now I am running into problems deploying Xamarin iOS apps on the iPad.

I can create an iOS app in xcode and deploy it successfully. However, when I try to build my Xamarin app, I get the error "No installed profiles match the installed iOS signing identities."

There are a few posts on the forum that talk about a similar problem. I have gone through all these posts. I have also downloaded (once again)  my iOS certificate from Apple developer portal and added it to my keychain store.

I still don't understand why I get the error. Would appreciate if someone can tell me how I can get the list of installed iOS signing identities and compare them against the list of provisioning profiles.

Also, when I look at my plist.info file, I see that, for key `CfBundleIdentifier`, the value is `replace_bundle_id`. I am wondering how I can tie this bundle id back to my provisioning profile. On Apple's portal, I see a bunch of provisioning profiles (I am part of an enterprise team). There is no field called bundle-id on these profiles. All each of them have is an app-id. Where do I related the bundle-id to the provisioning profile? Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to make it work. This is based on the feedback I received from the other two replies.

From the Apple developer portal, I looked at the ID of my app. This was in the form `com.mycompany.myproduct`. In my Xamarin iOS app's `plist.info`, the id was `replace_bundle_id`. I changed it to match the one from the portal.

Next, I cleaned the "Provisioning Profiles" directory on Mac and used xcode to create a test project and change the bundle id (from project options) to match the one on the portal. xcode automatically created a new profile.

This made the whole thing work. Now I am able to deploy and debug from my PC to iPad via Mac.

Our project was generated by Xamarin wizard a long time ago and used to work just fine until recently. I still do not know why `replace_bundle_id` worked in the past and stopped working all of a sudden. The only change I had made was that I upgraded the OSes on the Mac as well as my iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Provisioning profiles are all inside the directory: `/Users/m.piccotti/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

Usually when I have these kind of problems and no time to understand what's wrong, I simply delete everything inside that directory and I download again all the profiles from Xcode. Naturally you can try this only if you are sure that you'll be able again to download all the provisioning profiles you need.

Or it could be that you have to set the right provisioning profile for the project:
[image]

This info is saved into iOS.csproj, the element `CodesignProvision`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I cleaned up the directory and recreated the profiles. However, there was one more thing I had to do to make it work as explained in my answer. Regards.

Comment: This is super helpful! This will quite likely become my go to solution with such problems from now on :-D .

Comment: You are welcome @MartinZikmund, our job is looking for answers on StackOverflow and also my balance with it is still negative :)

Answer (score 1):

When you go to Apple Developer portal and check App IDs, you see the Name and ID of your app. The ID is your bundle ID. That you need to enter in your plist.
Based on that Xamarin will find your profiles.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This reply, along with the previous one, helped me solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, if your problem has been resolved, please mark the answer which helped you the most. Happy coding :)